# Obtaining updated page with HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

After I click on specific anchor on some html page (with usual browser), a new  appears on the page, what I can see with Chrome's instrumental tool. No reload of the page occur, it's just new  at the end of the page. But when I click on the anchor using HtmlUnit ( HtmlPage page = anchor.click() ) it starts to reload the whole page.

So the main question is how to click on the anchor without provoking a page reload. The second question is how to obtain an updated, not reloaded page, cos' the construciton itself "HtmlPage page = ... " looks like we're about to get a new, reloaded page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'click on the anchor without provoking a page reload'. There is no way in a real browser so there is also no way to do this in HtmlUnit.
If you are facing this kind of problems you can try to get this solved:

1. use the latest snapshot version of HtmlUnit.
2. use some proxy to monitor the real traffic (like Charles WebProxy). Do it for both, the real browser and HtmlUnit.
3. check for differences in the traffic
4. if you see some differences try to figure out why this happens. Usually there is a javascript function that does not work the same way as in the real browser.
5. if you can point to a single js problem open an issue (see [Submitting Javascript bugs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html) for more details)
6. (optional) provide a patch

The time to fix your issue usually depends on the amount of details you provide.